# simulating connection flakiness on windows phone 7 simulator for testing

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, testing, simulator

I am developing an application for windows phone 7. Now for testing my application on simulator. I want that simulator should have connection flakiness as we usually have on wp7 device.How can I achieve this please help.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone 8.0 SDK supports [network simulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206952%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). You can simulte 2G/3G/Wifi and no network.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to test the internet connection from the emulator.

You absolutely have to test it from a device...

The function "NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()" check if the smartphone is connected to the internet.
However, this function will always return true since the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure what are you asking for but take a look at this

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/12/09/checking-for-network-connectivity-in-windows-phone-7-sdk

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would just take Ethernet cable off and on to "simulate" flakiness.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to test things on a train to and from work. I gain & loose internet connectivity 3 or 4 times in my journey so it is ideal for me :)